# Why can't I divide the total number of bytes of a .BMP file by the color depth?

Tags: display, hex, color

I have a .BMP file resize.bmp.
[image]

The total number of bytes that encode pixels in this file is 320 bytes.

The color depth in this file is 3 bytes.
[image]
0x176 total number of bytes including Header

0x140 Total number of bytes without Header

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't have anything to do with circuit design.

Comment: I need this information to program the TFT display. Why is it possible to specify tags: hex, display, color?
Maybe I'm wrong, I don't know. Write, is it true that such questions cannot be written here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row of pixel data is padded up to a multiple of 4 bytes.

Specifications for .BMP format are widely available, the original ones made by Microsoft and there is good enough reference even at Wikipedia. Keep the specifications at hand for reference when writing code to handle .BMP files.

Comment: Thank you. Why is this necessary?

Comment: @stm The specs require an uncompressed RGB stride being doubleword aligned without further explanation why. Sometimes specs need to be taken as they are without knowing the reason how and why the specs became the way they are.